# How to use PostgreSQL array in WHERE IN clause?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, where-in

I am trying to simplify the following SQL statement (wrapped into function for clarity).

What is a simpler/natural syntactical way to use `array` inside `where ... in (/*array*/)` clause?
(without `select * from unnest(...)` boilerplate)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_items(p_ids int[])
 RETURNS SETOF text
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
  select t.name 
    from my_table t 
   where f.id in (select * from unnest(p_ids))
$$;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `IN` use `ANY`, this also removes the need to unnest

```
where f.id = any (p_ids)
```